# How do I configure/structure the dist directory and include images in Angular2 using the Angular-CLI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to make a build using 'ng build'. For my prod environment, I need my .js files to be nested within a /js directory.

I also need images to be moved from an /assets directory to this /dist directory.

Is this something that gets configured in the angular-cli.json?

note: I am using the angular-cli@webpack as well as rc.5

Answer (score 0):

All files placed in the "public" folder will be copied in the "dist" folder during the build. (for assets)

Comment: how would you get the main.bundle.js to be nested in a /js directory as well?

Comment: Probably in the next release there wouldn't be "public" folder anymore.